# Find appended text from txt file

Tags: c#

i want to write a code in a way,if there is a text file placed in a specified path, one of the users edited the file and entered new text and saved it.now,i want to get the text which is appended last time.
here am having file size for both before and after append the text

my text file size is 1204kb from that i need to take the end of 200kb text alone is it possible

Comment: my text file size is 1204kb from that i need to take the end of 200kb text alone is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the file pointer . Eg If you are using C language then you can go to the end of the file using fseek(fp,SEEK_END) and then use ftell(fp) which will give you the current position of the file pointer . After the user edits and saves the file , when you rerun the code you can check with the new position original position  . If the new position is greater than the original position offset those number of bytes with the file pointer

Answer (score 4):

This can only be done if you're monitoring the file size in real-time, since files do not maintain their own histories.

If watching the files as they are modified is a possibility, you could perhaps use a `FileSystemWatcher` and calculate the increase in file size upon any modification. You could then read the bytes appended since the file last changes, which would be very straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know how big the file was before the user appended the text? If not, there's no way of telling... files don't maintain a revision history (in most file systems, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

As [@Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) alludes to in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187415/find-appended-text-from-txt-file/1187447#1187447), the only way to tell specifically what text that was "appended", is by knowing how large the file was before it was changed. The rest of the characters is thus what was "appended".

Note that I quote appended above since I get two conflicting meanings from your question; edited and appended.

If the user only appends text, which is taken to mean "add more text only at the end", then the previous-size approach should in theory work.

However, if the user freely edits the text, by adding text in random spots, and perhaps even removing or changing existing text, then you need a whole 'nother approach to this.

If it's the latter, I might have something you could use, a binary patching implementation that can also be used to figure out from an older copy of the same file what was changed in a newer copy. It isn't easy to use, and might not give you exactly what you want, but as I said, it's hard to tell exactly what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is running the entire time, you could grab a copy of the file in memory.  Then in a separate thread periodically read the new file and compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to be notified when file is changed, use FileSystemWatcher. However, it will only notify you, when file is changed while your program is running and will not provide you with appended text. You will get only information about which file was changed.

```
     FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.txt");
     while (true)
     {
         var changedResult =
             watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Changed);
         Console.WriteLine(changedResult.Name);
     }
```

Or:

```
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.txt");
    watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;
    static void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
        Console.WriteLine(e.ChangeType);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution imo is to write a small app which has to be used to change the file in question. This application can then insert additional info into the file which allows you to keep the entire revision history.